# Termios input function not working

Tags: c++, keyboard

I have a function:

```
int term_option(int option)
{
    struct termios attributes;
    switch(option)
    {

    case 0: // Echo On
        if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        attributes.c_lflag |= ECHO;
        attributes.c_lflag |= ICANON;
        attributes.c_lflag |= ISIG;
        if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        break;

    case 1: // Echo Off
        if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        attributes.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);
        if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        break;

    case 2: // Wait for the keyboard to be touched
        if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        attributes.c_lflag    &= ~(ICANON);
        attributes.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;
        attributes.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
        if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        break;

    case 3:
        if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        attributes.c_lflag    &= ~(ICANON);
        attributes.c_lflag    &= ~(ISIG);
        attributes.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
        attributes.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
        if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&attributes) != 0) return (-1);
        break;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

When I call it with:

```
    term_option(1);
    term_option(3);
```

It does not return anything at all. In fact, it doesn't appear to even be executed. I'm not sure why. And yes, I did use the `termios.h` header file.
Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Here are the gdb results:

https://pastebin.com/u3g8Xafn

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger and set breakpoints to see if it's being run?

Comment: "It does not return anything at all" -- how can you tell, since you're not assigning the return value to anything.

Comment: I meant that it doesn't appear to be executing. And no, I haven't used a debugger.. yet.

Comment: Debugger first, SO last.

Comment: Can you post an MCVE that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ok. I used gdb with the program. I'll post the results.

Comment: I'm sorry. MCVE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'd have to release the code to do that... There is no way for me to explain, let alone show the problem i'm having in this medium.

Comment: Like I said, the code doesn't give any signs of it not working. It just simply doesn't work.

Comment: Let me also just say, that C++ isn't my preferred language. I know next to nothing about it.

Comment: You can't write a simple `main()` program that calls this function and demonstrates that it's not working?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on in the gdb output you posted. You don't show any breakpoints being set in the function. Are you sure you even got to the code that calls the function? It looks like the application crashed.

Comment: Yes. I can write a main() function. It's just difficult to show the error i'm getting. How do I show an error that produces no output?

Comment: If you can explain to me the "proper" way to use GDB, i'd be glad to learn.

Comment: You can describe what it's supposed to do, i.e. allow input without echoing.

Comment: Ok. What's it's supposed to do is limit the amount of characters that are echoed to the screen. As of right now, it's "doubling" the characters that are in the input buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure how any of this is relevant to an application like `EtherTerm`. It's a terminal emulator, but `termios` is used by programs that run in the terminal, not the terminal emulator itself.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the code you have at the master end of the pseudo-tty. It's not properly reacting to the signals that the slave sends in response to these `termios` calls, so it's not disabling its echoing.

Comment: Actually, because of the SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE "issue", it is echoing the characters. The actual author of the program `EtherTerm` is who gave me this "quick fix." But it isn't working. Which is why I posted it here.

Comment: That author, MercyFul Fate (his handle), is actually going to try to help me figure out this mess soon. I just thought i'd try to pursue a fix on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the baud rate that needs to be set.
With the machine you are using and the device you are interfacing with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I do that? Using `stty`?

Comment: Standard input is rarely connect to a real serial device these days, it's almost always a virtual terminal. Baud rate is not likely to be relevant.

Comment: Ok. The program i'm using is called `EtherTerm` .. I ported it from using X to using DirectFB on the console. I believe the problem is that `EtherTerm` "doesn't like" DirectFB. I changed all refrences of `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` to `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE`. I've tried `stty -echo`. No luck.

Comment: are you using USB interface with the external device? if yes, then using stty set the baud rate to match.

Comment: No. No USB devices.

Comment: @user2411434 The `termios()` functions only apply to terminal devices, not frame buffers.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. I didn't know that. Is there an alternative route?

Comment: Ok. I should better explain myself. The problem i'm having is that when I go to input text in the framebuffer, I get "doubled" characters. Like, for example, if I type "Hi", it outputs "HHii".

Comment: Ok. Apparently there's PDCurses. Which supposedly supports the framebuffer. I'll look into this further.